# How to turn off SSL 3.0 in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, security, ssl

To prevent POODLE vulnerability, I'd like to turn off SSL 3.0 on my server host. But before then, would like to test my app (it uses mainly standard Android APIs) still work with TLS without actually turning off SSL 3.0 on server side.

Is there a way to turn off SSL 3.0 in Android and iOS?

Cheers,
Tyn

Comment: This answer may help you on Android http://stackoverflow.com/a/27928360/127938

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about it here http://www.albertobarrera.net/?p=82 for iOS, in few words you have to change the TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol value to kTLSProtocol1 in the configuration object of the NSURLSession.