# How to manage HTTPS on a dev machine, with android?

Tags: android, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, sslv3

As HTTPS requires a certificate and a dns name, how are you supposed to work on your dev machine ?

Do you need a specific certificate and a dns name for your machine ?

I generated self signed certs but it causes too many problems with android with sslv3/poodle:

1/ You have to put some code to accept your self signed cert. I followed the recommendation from google, [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned).

2/ When you apply this and have a server, nginx, not supporting sslv3 which is good as sslv3 has a flaw, you get an exception saying that it tried to negotiate sslv3 but failed.

3/ Then there are some rare advices on how to bypass the sslv3 issue by providing a modified socketFactory. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633349/disable-ssl-as-a-protocol-in-httpsurlconnection) for example. But mixing 1/ with this becomes very difficult for me.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "it causes too many problems" -> Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @2Dee I added more details

Comment: Cool ! I unfortunately can't answer your question, but maybe an upvote will help draw attention to it ;)