# SSLHandshakeException using HttpsURLConnection in Android

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection, sslv3

Details about my app:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "My application id"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2"
    }
```

I'm using HttpsURLConnection for Login authentication.But now i'm facing **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException** that too on devices running below android lollipop.Authentication is working as expected on devices running OS verions abouve 5.Please let me know your suggestions for this issue.

Here is the code i'm using :

```
    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("URL to my application");

        String authStr = username + ":" + password;

        String authEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(authStr.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncoded);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setConnectTimeout(120000);
        int code = conn.getResponseCode();

        if(code ==200){
            for(int i=0;i<conn.getHeaderFields().size();i++){
                String value = conn.getHeaderField(i);

                HeaderElement headerElement =  BasicHeaderValueParser.parseHeaderElement(value, new BasicHeaderValueParser());

                if(headerElement.getName().equals("SMSESSION")){

                    cookieString = SMSESSION+"="+headerElement.getValue();
                    Log.d("validhdvaluelogin",cookieString);
                    cookieeditor.putString(ArticleListActivity.CURRENT_COOKIE,
                            cookieString);
                    cookieeditor.apply();

                    return true;
                }


            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }



    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }


    if (conn != null) {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    return false;
```

And here is the exception :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL       
handshake aborted: ssl=0xb87b0350: Failure in SSL library, usually a    
protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake            
failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0xa9092990:0x00000000)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:661)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:632)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:70)
at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:172)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.ericsson.labs.it.infoservicemx.network.AuthComm.login(AuthComm.java:148)
at com.ericsson.labs.it.infoservicemx.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:312)
at com.ericsson.labs.it.infoservicemx.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:230)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb87b0350: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0xa9092990:0x00000000)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
... 23 more
```

Comment: I think its related questions http://stackoverflow.com/a/27928360/3436179

Comment: Solution provided in that post didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

I have finally found solution to my problem.
By using NetCipher library for httpsurlconnection.
Instead of using:

```
HttpsUrlConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Use:

```
HttpsUrlConnection conn =  NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(url);
```

This solved my SSLv3 handshake issue.

Comment: Here the question is how to resolve SSL issue with HttpUrlConnection, not which library we should use !!!

Comment: get server certificate and add to trusted certificate in your httpconnection