# Android Studio Java: Can't download image from web into the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to download an image from the web and display it on the app by clicking a button . I've written this code in MainAcitivity.java .

```
package com.example.guessthecelebrity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    public void clickFunction (View view) {

        ImageDownloadTask task = new ImageDownloadTask();
        Bitmap myImage;
        try {
            myImage = task.execute("https://www.bizain.com/content/images/wordpress/2018/04/warren_buffett-1-571x400.jpg").get();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                return myBitmap;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Result","Failed in Background");
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    }
}
```

It is showing the following error in the logcat when I click the button to download the image.

```
2021-08-19 20:20:26.956 32442-32484/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=6.08ms min=5.10ms max=8.95ms count=61
2021-08-19 20:20:27.264 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
2021-08-19 20:20:27.265 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:363)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.265 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.265 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1089)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.266 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.267 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.267 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.267 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.268 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:731)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.268 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.268 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.268 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.269 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.269 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.269 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.269 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.270 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.273 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.273 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.273 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.273 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.274 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.274 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.274 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity$ImageDownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:44)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.274 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity$ImageDownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:37)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.274 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.275 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.275 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.275 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.276 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.276 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.276 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
2021-08-19 20:20:27.277 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:719)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.277 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.277 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:570)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.277 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.278 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.278 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:505)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.278 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:425)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.278 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:353)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.278 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.279 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.279 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:163)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.279 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:255)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.280 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1638)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.280 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.281 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.281 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.281 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.282 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     ... 27 more
2021-08-19 20:20:27.282 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
2021-08-19 20:20:27.282 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.283 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.284 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.285 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.285 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:301)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.285 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:715)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.286 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     ... 43 more
2021-08-19 20:20:27.286 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException: Certificate not valid until Sat Aug 28 20:29:17 GMT+05:30 2021 (compared to Thu Aug 19 20:20:27 GMT+05:30 2021)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.289 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.checkValidity(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:264)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.289 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(BasicChecker.java:194)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.289 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:144)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.290 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
2021-08-19 20:20:27.290 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     ... 48 more
2021-08-19 20:20:27.290 32442-32567/com.example.guessthecelebrity I/Result: Failed in Background
2021-08-19 20:20:27.292 32442-32442/com.example.guessthecelebrity I/Choreographer: Skipped 325 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

What did I do wrong? I have watched videos regarding this and they had the exact same code and it worked perfectly for them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619889/sslhandshakeexception-using-httpsurlconnection-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to solve the problem:**

You are using `HttpURLConnection`, but you have an **https**-URL. Instead use `HttpsURLConnection`.
That should fix the error.

Tip:

We are living in the 21st century and there are plenty of libraries, which will help you with this task.

1. [**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Import:

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}
```

Use:

```
Glide.with(this).load("https://www.bizain.com/content/images/wordpress/2018/04/warren_buffett-1-571x400.jpg").into(imageView);
```

2. [**Picasso**](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Import:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

Use:

```
Picasso.get().load("https://www.bizain.com/content/images/wordpress/2018/04/warren_buffett-1-571x400.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Try it out!